# XPages : Missing checkboxes with Bootstrap theme

Tags: xpages

In an XPage contact list I use chekboxes to delete docs (records).
While using the application theme `Bootstrap3.2.0_flat` I do not see those checkboxes. Neither in a browser nor in Notes.

Switching to `OneUI xxx` I see those checkboxes in the browser and Notes.
Does anyone got an idea whats going on here ?

Please see screenshots below

OneUI view with checkboxes

[image]

Bootstrap view : without checkboxes

[image]

Designer Layout

[image]

Designer Properties

[image]

---

UPDATE :

I made a preview test with Bootstrap and OneUI and copied the relevant HTMl line from the browser.

This HTML line is with OneUI theme and it has the `checkBox input` embedded

```
<td class="xspColumnViewStart" role="gridcell">
  <input name="view:_id1:viewPanel1:1:viewColumn1:_colcbox" class="xspCheckBoxViewColumn" id="view:_id1:viewPanel1:1:viewColumn1:_colcbox" style="margin: 0px 2px; height: 12px;" type="checkbox" value="A42" onchangetrigger="early-onclick">
  <a class="xspLinkViewColumn" id="view:_id1:viewPanel1:1:viewColumn1:_internalColumnLink" href="#">Tulip Ltd.</a>
</td>
```

This HTML line is with Bootstrap theme generated and it misses the`checkBox input`.

```
<td role="gridcell" class="xspBootstrapRowIcon">
  <a id="view:_id1:viewPanel1:1:viewColumn1:_internalColumnLink" href="#">Tulip Ltd.</a>
</td>
```

Anyone has an idea to this issue ?

Comment: You likely have a CSS conflict somewhere. Dig into the Chrome tools and see what is happening. You might have to turn off resource optimization to help troubleshoot.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this also an issue when previewing XPages with Notes. You think this is still an CSS issue ?

Comment: Yes I do. For some reason the built in bootstrap isn't working correctly. I have an idea that I will put in an answer.

Comment: By the way I am using FireFox (v41.0.2)  but I guess that is not the point

Comment: What version of the ExtLib do you have installed?

Comment: @Brian - ExtensionLibraryOpenNTF-901v00_14.20150831-1301

Comment: I have 901v00_15 installed. But I don't think there were any changes between releases 14 and 15 in the area you are having a problem. And for me, the checkboxes on the viewPanel work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Ben,

I suspect that you have a CSS conflict between XPages and the built-in bootstrap that is part of the extension library. This would be very hard to find without sitting down with you. My suggestion is that you load bootstrap yourself instead of using the built-in theme. I can't say for sure that this will solve your problem but I suspect that it will. (One thing you left our was browser type and version which *could* be a factor).

Prior to being integrated in the Extension Library, this was how we used Bootstrap with XPages. While I think it is good to have it there, it would not surprise me if there CSS conflicts. I have experienced this while using OneUI.

Installing bootstrap your is not difficult. Here are directions: http://bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/site.nsf/article.xsp?documentId=3F14A575DDA02986C1257B6B002B7E89&action=openDocument

A side benefit is that you are not tied to a specific Bootstrap version, and can upgrade without waiting on IBM.

***Disclaimer note***: When you consider my answer, please bear in mind that I write  as someone who prefers to control my own resources, and has worked thru strange CSS issues with OneUI which leads to my skepticism with the built-in bootstrap theme.

Comment: Thanks for your answer at the moment. I agree to your note but currently for me it will be challange to deinstall the Extension Lib and to install Bootstrap independently. Also with the risk of getting more troubles. I wait a bit for more answers, maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: I understand totally. Keep trying to use Chrome tools to determine what happens to the check boxes.  Determine if the CSS is being overwritten, but first make sure they are being rendered in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I answer here my question, because the issue dissapeared after I relaunched Domino Designer and toggled the `Build Automatically` item in the `Project` menu. Weired ??!!